# Can i convert a XML citation to bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, xml

I need to convert to bibtex all that a XML citation contains, like it

```
<reference anchor="RFC1180" target="https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc1180">
<front>
<title>TCP/IP tutorial</title>
<author initials="T.J." surname="Socolofsky" fullname="T.J. Socolofsky">
<organization/>
</author>
<author initials="C.J." surname="Kale" fullname="C.J. Kale">
<organization/>
</author>
<date year="1991" month="January"/>
<abstract>
<t>
This RFC is a tutorial on the TCP-IP protocol suite, focusing particularly on the steps in forwarding an IP datagram from source host to destination host through a router. It does not specify an Internet standard.
</t>
</abstract>
</front>
<seriesInfo name="RFC" value="1180"/>
<seriesInfo name="DOI" value="10.17487/RFC1180"/>
</reference>
```

This citation is about a RFC that i should put in a article, centainly this is a example. I have a protocol list that can be hard to do by hand.

It's possible to i convert it this XML citation to Bibtex to accelerate my production and build my citations?

Comment: Would using the DOI to convert it to a bibtex quotation, using, for example, https://www.doi2bib.org, be sufficient for your needs? Or do you need all fields that the XML contains?

Comment: All fields, i will edit it in my question

Comment: Do you only need this one citation? Do it by hand!

Comment: No, i don't need only this citation, @DG', i have a lot, but i use only this to show a example what i want. I will edit it to in my question. Thanks.

Comment: what XML scheme is this? is it documented somewhere? should bibtex contain the same fields as the XML file, or do you want to use some standard bibtex styles, or biblatex?

Comment: After searching a little, I am guessing you are using this format here: [www.rfc-editor.org/ref-example/](https://www.rfc-editor.org/ref-example/).  If that is the case, you could try the following (which I found after searching for `rfc-editor xml to bibtex`): https://www.tm.uka.de/~bless/bibrfcindex.html

Comment: Here is a direct link to whole thing: https://www.tm.uka.de/~bless/rfc.bib

Comment: Awesome, this help me a lot!!! Thanks!